# Osmdroid tile sources shows blank map android

Tags: android, osmdroid

my code is below

```
mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", 0, 18, 256, ".png",
    new String[] { "https://maps.tilehosting.com/c/48533dee-0f32-42a2-a6db-315bbc7ecca8/styles/bdbasic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=xxxxxxxxxx" }) {

    @Override
    public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
        return getBaseUrl()
                + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                + mImageFilenameEnding;
    }
});
```

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources

My Version is 6.0.3
 [image: map blank image]

Comment: Have you configured your map on Google Developer Console? you have to provide the key to load the map.

Comment: i am using osm (open street map) , their default tile source factory work well and shows map in my app but for production i use my own tile source where key hide by "xxx" but it dont work ..where is the problem i cant find out..

Comment: You need to generate a different key for the production. Debug ket won't work.

Comment: it is our production key and working well in our web application. @Jaymin

Comment: Have you checked your LogCat?

Comment: LogCat return 
https://maps.tilehosting.com/c/48533dee-0f32-42a2-a6db-315bbc7ecca8/styles/bdbasic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=xxxxx/19/226463/393823.png

Comment: You have the issue with the key.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the string you copy pasted into your code:

```
https://maps.tilehosting.com/c/48533dee-0f32-42a2-a6db-315bbc7ecca8/styles/bdbasic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=xxxxxxxxxx"
```

That's apparently some example from some documentation of your tile provider. {z},{x} and {y} are variables and must be dynamically added by osmdroid. And xxxxx shuld be replaced by your API key.

You should use only the base part in your code:

```
https://maps.tilehosting.com/c/48533dee-0f32-42a2-a6db-315bbc7ecca8/styles/bdbasic/
```

The rest of the URL is added in the `getTileURLString` method. You have also a mistake there. As you can see in the example, the order of params should be z(zoom) x and y. You have x and y swapped in your code.

The example also hints that you should have some API key. So check the documentation of the tile provider again and obtain the key if neccessary. You can than pass the key via the parameter which now contains only ".png". You'll need to change it to ".png?key=yourkeyandnotthisstringorxxxxx".

In the end you should endup with something like this:

```
mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", 0, 18, 256, ".png?key=yourkeyandnotthisstringorxxxxx",
    new String[] { "https://maps.tilehosting.com/c/48533dee-0f32-42a2-a6db-315bbc7ecca8/styles/bdbasic/" }) {

    @Override
    public String getTileURLString(long pMapTileIndex) {
        return getBaseUrl()
                + MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)
                + "/" + MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)
                + "/" + MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)
                + mImageFilenameEnding;
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems that something has loaded.Maybe some ocean? Can you zoom the map? An/or pan?

Comment: @KaziAshrafulAzam ok, that would mean there's still something wrong. You could try to swap the x and y coordinates again, maybe they were correct in the first place (even though that would mean that the example/url was incorrect in the documentation of the provider). There's also some format (TMS) mentioned in the osmdroid documentation when something needs to be done to the zoom level. But I don't know more about that. I have no idea what your tile provider actually uses.

Answer (score 1):

Are you set user agent?

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IConfigurationProvider provider = Configuration.getInstance();
        provider.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);

        provider.setOsmdroidBasePath(getStorage());
        provider.setOsmdroidTileCache(getStorage());

        // provider.setDebugMapTileDownloader(true);
        //provider.setDebugTileProviders(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.osm_activity);
}
```